# How to keep only the rows that cumulate 80% of a column whitin of each group of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, cumsum

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df_dict = dict(
        group = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
        model = [model 2,model 4,model 7,model 6,model 5,model 2,model 5,model 7,model 3,model 4,model 3,model 6,model 5,model 1,model 2,model 7,model 4],
        value = [10,4.6,2,1.3,1,10,3,3,2,0.9,4,2.7,2,1,1,1,0.9],
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

For each group, I want to keep the models that cover 80% of the total of the variable "value".

In this example, what the output should be:

```
Group | Model   | value |
-------------------------
1     | model 2 | 10    |
1     | model 4 | 4.6   |
1     | model 7 | 2     |
2     | model 2 | 10    |
2     | model 5 | 3     |
2     | model 7 | 3     |
3     | model 3 | 4     |
3     | model 6 | 2.7   |
3     | model 5 | 2     |
3     | model 1 | 1     |
3     | model 2 | 1     |
--------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try multiple `groupby`

```
df = df.sort_values(['group','value'],ascending=[True,False])
g = df.groupby('group')['value']
df = df[df.index<=((g.cumsum()/g.transform('sum'))>0.8).groupby(df['group']).transform('idxmax')]
df
Out[120]: 
    group    model  value
0       1  model 2   10.0
1       1  model 4    4.6
2       1  model 7    2.0
5       2  model 2   10.0
6       2  model 5    3.0
7       2  model 7    3.0
10      3  model 3    4.0
11      3  model 6    2.7
12      3  model 5    2.0
13      3  model 1    1.0
14      3  model 2    1.0
```

Comment: It seems this code relies on the values being sorted in descending order. Is that correct or am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: I suspect the input probably is sorted, but it's good to add the code to make sure it is.

Comment: btw it's a lovely piece of code - took me a while to get my head around it! :)

Comment: Yes, the input was sorted in a step before.